# Writing and debugging a min program in asm

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, att

I am trying to write a program to find the minimum value of a list of integers in asm. Here is what I have so far:

```
.section .data

data_items:
    .long 2,3,4,5,1,9,10            # set 10 as the sentinal value

.section text

.globl _start
_start:

    # %ebx holds min
    # %edi holds index (destination index)
    # %eax current data item

    movl $255, %ebx                 # set the current min to 255 
    movl $0, %edi                   # the index is also zero
    

start_loop:

    movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax  # set %eax equal to the current data item
    cmpl $10, %eax                  # compare %eax with zero to see if we should exit 
    je exit_loop                    # if it's the sentinel value, exit
    incl %edi                       # increment the index
    cmpl %eax, %edi                 # compare the current value to the current min
    jge start_loop                  # if it's not less than the current value, go to start
    movl %eax, %ebx                 # move the current value if less that the current min
    jmp start_loop                  # always go back to the start if we've gotten this far  

exit_loop:
    movl $1, %eax                   # push the linux system call to %eax (1=exit)
    int $0x80                       # give linux control (so it will exit)
```

When I run this, I get the following:

> $ as min.s -o min.o && ld min.o -o min && ./min
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

How is one supposed to debug asm? For example, at least in C the compiler tells you what the error might be and the line number, whereas here I know just about nothing. (Note: the error is having `.section text` instead of `.section .text` but how would one figure that out?)

Comment: If you create a section with a non-standard name and don't give it any attributes, it is by default readable and writable, but not executable.  Thus, your code ends up in a non-executable section, causing a segmentation fault when the processor refuses to execute the first execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very possible in C to write a program that compiles with no warnings but crashes (e.g. NULL pointer deref), and you'll see exactly the same thing.  It's much more likely in asm, though.

You debug asm with a debugger, GDB for example.  See tips at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  And if you make any system calls, use `strace` to see what your program is actually doing.

To debug this, you'd run it under GDB and notice that it segfaulted on the first instruction, `movl $255, %ebx`.  It doesn't access memory so code-fetch must have faulted.  So there must be something wrong with your sections that resulted in your code in section linked into a non-executable segment of your executable.

`objdump -d` would also have given you a hint: it disassembles the `.text` section by default, and this program doesn't have one.

---

The reason `text` instead of `.text` causes this problem is that the defaults for sections with random names that aren't one of the few specially-recognized ones are read+write without exec.

In GAS, **use `.text` or `.data`**, special shortcut directives for `.section .text` or .data which avoid this problem for those sections.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Text.html

But not all "standard" sections have special directives, you do still need `.section .rodata` to switch to the read-only data section, where you *should* have put your array.  (read, no write.  On newer toolchains, also no exec).  Instead of switching to the `.bss` section, though, you can use `.comm` or `.lcomm`  (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/bss.html)

---

Another possible problem is that you're building this 32-bit code as a 64-bit executable (unless you're using a 32-bit-only install where `as --32` is the default).  Using 32-bit addressing modes works in 64-bit modes, truncating the address to 32 bits.  That works when accessing static data in a position-dependent executable on Linux, because all code+data is linked into the low 2GiB of virtual address space.

But any access to `(%esp)` or `-4(%ebp)` or whatever would fault because the stack in a 64-bit process is mapped to a high address with non-zero bits outside the low 32.

You'd notice that problem in GDB because `layout reg` would show all 16 64-bit integer registers, RAX..R15.

Comment: Thanks -- what are some good gdb / strace links for this? The x86 has hundreds (if not thousands) of links so not sure where to start.

Comment: @TagC198: There's a section at the bottom of the tag wiki about debugging.  I don't know of a good tutorial that tells beginners how to get started debugging; I already knew a lot of about low level systems programming before I started doing much assembly so problems like this already made sense before I had them.